# SQL: Update all rows except one of each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this. Column "Mail sent" has either the values "0" or a date.

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
| Ordernumber |      Email      | Mail sent  |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
|           1 | john.d@mail.com | 01.01.2018 |
|           2 | john.d@mail.com | 02.01.2018 |
|           3 | anne.t@mail.com |          0 |
|           4 | anne.t@mail.com | 04.01.2018 |
|           5 | anne.t@mail.com | 05.01.2018 |
|           6 | jeff.k@mail.com | 06.01.2018 |
|           7 | jeff.k@mail.com | 07.01.2018 |
|           8 | jeff.k@mail.com |          0 |
|           9 | mary.k@mail.com | 09.01.2018 |
|          10 | sam.b@mail.com  |          0 |
|          11 | sam.b@mail.com  |          0 |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
```

I want to update the "Mail sent" column, so that for every Email there is at most only one date in "Mail sent". Constraint: The lowest Ordernumber of every Email that has a date should keep the date, the rest should be set to "0".

The result of the table should be:

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
| Ordernumber |      Email      | Mail sent  |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
|           1 | john.d@mail.com | 01.01.2018 |
|           2 | john.d@mail.com |          0 |
|           3 | anne.t@mail.com |          0 |
|           4 | anne.t@mail.com | 04.01.2018 |
|           5 | anne.t@mail.com |          0 |
|           6 | jeff.k@mail.com | 06.01.2018 |
|           7 | jeff.k@mail.com |          0 |
|           8 | jeff.k@mail.com |          0 |
|           9 | mary.k@mail.com | 09.01.2018 |
|          10 | sam.b@mail.com  |          0 |
|          11 | sam.b@mail.com  |          0 |
+-------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Comment: Why are you storing `0` in a date column?  You should be using `NULL`.

Comment: First normalise your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
update likethis lt join
       (select email, min(ordernumber) as minon
        from likethis
        where mailsent <> 0
        group by email
       ) lt2
       on lt.email = lt2.email
    set lt.mailsent = 0
    where lt.mailsent <> 0 and lt.ordernumber > lt2.minon;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwRXFy2wHFfxFW3KZTNrVC/0) is the db fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, this query doesn't deliver the desired results. Please run this DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwRXFy2wHFfxFW3KZTNrVC/0

Comment: Your edit also just updates the first email (john.d@mail.com) in the table. The other values are unchanged.

Comment: @AndiPower . . . Thank you for setting up the DB Fiddle.  The original query should have failed with something like "email not aggregated", because the `GROUP BY` was missing in the subquery.